# Can I get ${\rm{Inn}}(S_3)={\rm{Aut}}(S_3)$ from $\varphi\in{\rm{Aut}}(S_3)$ being equivalent to a faithful transitive action of $S_3$ on $\{1,2,3\}$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, automorphism-group

An automorphism of $S_3$, say $\varphi$, is equivalent to a faithful action of $S_3$ on the set $X:=\{1,2,3\}$. The orbit equations $3=1+1+1$ and $3=1+2$ are ruled out, because they would both imply $\operatorname{ker}\varphi=\bigcap_{i\in X}\operatorname{Stab}(i)\ne\{()\}$. Therefore, the only option left is this action to be also transitive. To sum up, this action has stabilizers which:

1. trivially intersect;
2. are conjugate in $S_3$.

Can I use 1 and 2 to prove that $\varphi$ is inner?

Comment: Your first statement would not be true for $S_6$ which has automorphisms which aren't equivalent to faithful actions on the underlying set. Your logic generally is unclear in showing how one statement follows from another. $S_3$ is a small group and any automorphism must take each element to another element of the same order - you should be able to find a set of three things on which any automorphism will act (other ways of doing this are also available).

Comment: @MarkBennet I disagree! The first statement is true for any $S_n$. An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ can be defined as a homomorphism $\phi:G \to {\rm Sym}(X)$ (there are other definitions, but they are equivalent to this one), and the action is faithful if $\ker \phi$ is trivial. So if $G = {\rm Sym}(X)$, then a faithful action is precisely an autopmorphism of ${\rm Sym}(X)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am not quibbling with the fact that a permutation of the underlying set gives an automorphism, but it is not true that all automorphisms arise in this way. The outer automorphisms of $S_6$ act differently and do not preserve cycle-type.

Comment: @MarkBennet It is true that there are outer automorphisms of $S_6$ that do not preserve cycle type, but that does not contradict the first sentence in this post, which is correct as stated for any $S_n$, including $S_6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I've been in meetings - I'm losing a sense of which set we are talking about in terms of a faithful action: it may just be my brain. But if we are talking about the same set, a counting argument shows that the number of elements is restricted to the size of the symmetric group. $S_6$ would have actions involving two different sets, I think? The way I read it the conclusion seems to be implied by the first sentence - but maybe I'm reading it wrongly.

Comment: @MarkBennet, here I make explicit the statement which implicitly I started with, so as to make easier a true/false confirmation of it: for any $n$, every automorphism of $S_n$ is equivalent to a faithful action of $S_n$ on the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$. (For $n=3$, this (faithful) action is also transitive.)

Comment: It might help to explicitly define the bijection $\mathrm{Aut}(S_n)\leftrightarrow (S_n\times \mathbf{n}\mapsto \mathbf{n})$ that you're envisioning. (I should be clear here that $\mathbf{n}$ is of course the set $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and I don't mean the set of all functions from $S_n\times \mathbf{n}$ to $\mathbf{n}$, but only the faithful group actions.)

Comment: Obviously there's a 'canonical' group action $S_n\times\mathbf{n}\mapsto\mathbf{n}$ given by $\alpha(\langle\phi, m\rangle)=\phi(m)$ and I presume this action corresponds to the identity automorphism in your bijection, but I don't see specifically how you're defining group actions corresponding to other automorphisms. Is it just $\alpha_\sigma(\langle\phi,m\rangle)=\left(\sigma(\phi)\right)(m)$ where $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(S_n)$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thank you for your inputs. I'll review them as soon as I can.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't recall understand why the first sentence in this post is causing such confusion. As I pointed out in my first comment, it is an immediate consequence of the definition of a group action (at least of the definition that I use). Yes, it is just $\alpha(\langle \phi,m \rangle) = (\sigma(\phi))(m)$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I just assumed (naively, but seemingly this is correct) that, if every $G$-action on $X$ is equivalent to a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to\operatorname{Sym}(X)$, then every embedding $G\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ is equivalent to a faithful action $G\times X\to X$. Now take $G=S_n$ and $X=\{1,\dots,n\}$ to conclude that the embeddings of $S_n$ into itself (i.e. the automorphisms of $S_n$) are equivalent to a faithful action of $S_n$ on $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: @MarkBennet An action on one set of size $6$ transfers at once to an action on any other set of size $6$ (in many ways). But I seem to remember that the two actions of $A_6$ on $6$ sets extend to the action of $M_{12}$ on a $12$-set ...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, an answer is desired. The answer is certainly 'no', because everything written in the question is also true for $S_6$, where not every automorphism is inner (and other permutation groups as well). Thus the two properties cannot be used to prove that every automorphism is inner.

This was why all of the comments are talking about $S_6$ (or $M_{12}$, which also has an outer automorphism).

More prosaic than the outer automorphism of $S_6$, the group $A_3$ also satisfies the conditions, and obviously has an outer automorphism.

Comment: How can we prove that every automorphism of $S_6$ is equivalent to a (faithful and) *transitive* action on $\{1,\dots,6\}$? I can't easily see it from the "residual orbit equation analysis" as done for $S_3$ case in the OP. So, I'm still unsure that really *everything* written in the question is also true for $S_6$.

Comment: $S_6$ has a big simple subgroup of index $2$. Every transitive action of $S_6$ is either on $1$ or $2$ points and has $A_6$ in the kernel, or on at least six points as $|S_6|=6!$. Or if you prefer choose $A_6$ instead, which has either trivial or faithful actions and certainly cannot be on fewer than six points.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer is "yes, one can, although you haven't finished doing so." It is indeed true that an automorphism of $S_n$ is a map $\phi : S_n \to S_n$ and thus can be thought of as an action of $S_n$ on $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n \}$.

It is also true that this action will necessarily be faithful and transitive: If it were not faithful, then $\phi$ would have a kernel, contrary to the claim that $\phi$ is an automorphism and, if it were not transitive, then the image of $\phi$ would land in $S_{a_1} \times S_{a_2} \times \cdots \times S_{a_k}$, where $a_j$ are the orbit sizes, contradicting that $\phi$  is an automorphism.

And, as you say, this implies that there is a subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ with index $n$ and $\bigcap_{g \in S_n} gHg^{-1} = \{ e \}$.

On the other hand, all of this is correct for arbitrary $n$ and, when $n=6$, then $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$, acting on the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_5)$, is a subgroup $H$ with the required properties; this gives rise to the outer automorphism of $S_6$. So you are not done, you actually need to rule out such an $H$.

Of course, the group $S_3$ is small enough that you can simply list all index $3$ subgroups of $S_3$ by hand, and perhaps that is what you intended to do. But something like that is what you need to do to finish the proof.

Comment: I completely disagree (obviously, since my answer says that you cannot do it). Since $A_3$ also satisfies all of the same statements the OP made, you need to do something else. And then once you do that other thing, you don't need these original statements. So the answer can be construed to be 'yes', but only in the sense that any true statement implies any other true statement.

Comment: I disagree, though you are pointing out that there is another issue the OP needs to address. In general, if $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup of index $n$, then we get an action of $G$ on $G/H$ but, in order to make this into a map $G \to S_n$, we need to choose a numbering of the cosets in $G/H$. Two different numberings will give maps $G \to S_n$ which are conjugate with respect to the target $S_n$, but not necessarily conjugate with respect to $G$. This is what happens with $A_n$ for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: However, if $\bigcap g H g^{-1} = \{ e \}$ and $|G| = n!$, then the map $G \to S_n$ will necessarily be an isomorphism, so the conjugacy class of $G \to S_n$ will be independent of the choice of numbering.

Comment: It really is true that proving $Out(S_n)$ is trivial is equivalent, modulo arguments which are easier than this main task, to showing that the only index $n$ subgroup $H$ with $\bigcap gHg^{-1} = \{ e \}$ is $S_{n-1}$ (and its conjguates).

Comment: So in addition to the facts here, you need that $G$ is in fact of order $n!$, and that $G$ has no subgroups of index $n$ other than the obvious ones. (The alternative proof is to show that any automorphism leaves transpositions invariant and acts transitively on Coxeter generators, which is more transparent.) But the two pieces of information you want are the salient points here, and not those given in the question. I can see your point, but normally when we say 'can I use X to prove Y?', if there are examples with X and not Y, the answer is 'no'.